# rust ash (vulkan), how can I test the debug name of a struct?

Tags: debugging, rust, graphics, vulkan

Say I use the DebugUtils object to set the name of a logical device, i.e. a `vk::Device`. How can I trigger a validation message involving the object to test that the name matches my expectation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to forcefully do something that the validation layers pickup. E.g. creating a buffer with a wrong alignment or flags.

Another (better) option is to run your application through [RenderDoc](https://renderdoc.org/). It'll display debug names in the trace, so you can easily see if naming of e.g. the device worked properly. You can find all Vulkan resources in the "Resource Inspector":

[image]